# Groovy arguments with spaceship operator in unique closure

Tags: groovy, parameters, arguments, closures, unique

I'm not very familiar to closures, and I have a, maybe, nooby question.
In Groovy documentations there's an example of unique() method of the class collection.

And one of them uses the spaceship operator.
I know that in:

```
a <=> b
```

spaceship operator returns -1 if a < b, 0 if a==b and 1 if a>b, like the compareTo.

In the Groovy Unique with closure example:

```
assert [2,3,4] == [2,3,3,4].unique { a, b -> a <=> b }
```

1.- What does a, b arguments means in a collection?
is "a" the [n] position and "b" [n+1]?

2.- The spaceship operator will return -1, 0 or 1
what does that do with the unique method? is there any difference with just using unique()? I tried both ways and it keeps returning me the sames results

Thanks in advance

Comment: The "spaceship" operator refered to in the title is known as the comparison operator in other languages

Comment: yes, like I said in the question, I know the spaceship operator is like (the same) as `compareTo()`. I just didn't know how the arguments worked in a collection with more than two elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `a` and `b` are just two items in the collection. It doesn't really matter what order they are in. What you're really doing is passing a closure to `unique()`, and the closure defines how to compare the items. The closure will be called by Groovy's `unique()` when it's needed to compare two items.
2. The no-arg version of `unique()` uses `compareTo()` on the items in the collection. The spaceship operator is another way to call `compareTo()`, which means that yes, `unique { a, b -> a <=> b }` is identical to `unique()`.

Comment: Thanks @doelleri. I knew I was passing a closure to unique(), I just didn't know how the 2 arguments worked in a list with more than two elements.
so, `a` and `b` means to compare one element of the list to any/all the others one by one?
Thanks again.